# Selenium Firefox - element not visible when 1st match is hidden but 2nd is visible

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-firefoxdriver

`Firefox` times out when trying to locate an element that is visible but the first match is hidden.

From [www.usps.com](http://www.usps.com), the following `xpath`- `//a[.='Mail & Ship']` followed by `//a[.='Calculate a Price']` opens https://postcalc.usps.com/

**The above works in IE and Chrome.** However in FF it times out with-

> Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located
>   by By.xpath: //a[.='Calculate a Price']

Code used is

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath))).click();
```

Using `Firepath`, I see there are two matches for `//a[.='Calculate a Price']` with the first one hidden under QuickTools menu. During test execution, when I manually click QuickTools menu to reveal "Calculate a Price", the test proceeds.

Is this a bug? Or is this expected behavior? 
Is there a workaround?

Many thanks!

Comment: try this two xpath. `//a[@class='menu--tier-one-link menu--item'][contains(text(), 'Mail & Ship')]`   another xpath is   `//a[@class='menu--tier-two-link'][@href='https://postcalc.usps.com/']`

Comment: Thanks I know I can craft a better xpath. However I was trying to understand the difference in behavior of finding elements between the different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathgoeshere)`, the singular "find_element" means selenium will find the first xpath that matches your argument, and stop there.  In this case, the first element with that xpath is hidden, so waiting till it turns visible won't happen.

There are several workarounds. I think the easiest is to find the unique xpath of the element you want to use.

`//a[.='Calculate a Price']` could be any of these elements:

```
<a class="quick-tools--link quick-tools--calcprice" href="https://postcalc.usps.com/">Calculate a Price</a>`

<a class="left-nav--link firepath-matching-node" href="/calculateretailpostage/welcome.htm" target="">Calculate a Price</a>`

<a class="menu--tier-two-link" href="https://postcalc.usps.com/">Calculate a Price</a>`
```

You can specify which one by adding a second selector to your Xpath:

`//a[.='Calculate a Price' and @class='quick-tools--link quick-tools--calcprice']`

`//a[.='Calculate a Price' and @class='menu--tier-two-link']`

Comment: The javadoc is not very clear in that it will find the first element regardless of visibility. I would expect it to attempt to find a visible element. Either way there seems to be inconsistent behavior between browsers.